# Dataset of common typos in English

Tags: data-request, language, nlp, english

I am looking for a dataset of common [typos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error) in English. Ideally, it should mention the frequency of typo.

Comment: can you be more specific? is that possible in this context? i want to say, frequency of what -> while trying to write a document, answer an email, etc. but i'm not even sure if that's a valid question...

Comment: @albert typos when typing using a computer keyboard. E.g. "hello wprld!" has one typo.

Comment: True typos, or do you also want spelling mistakes?  swapped letters, dropped letter, or mistakes from hitting an adjacent letter (either in place of or in addition to) would qualify as a typo.  Bad spelling is something different, as is using the incorrect homophone or using a British spelling variant in American English.

Comment: @Joe I am interested in both: do you think it's best to ask two separate questions?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt : I don't know, but it's important to be detailed, as there might be different studies that either distinguish or conflate the two.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to several [corpora of commonly misspelled words](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~ROGER/corpora.html) in several varieties of English - list includes the [Birbeck Spelling Error corpus](http://ota.ox.ac.uk/headers/0643.xml)